# java.io.FileNotFoundException(Access is denied) IDE Fatal Errors

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception, access-denied

I'm a novice user of Android studio. While I'm using it, an error message has kept coming up. I tried to change the folder's property into the full access by user and administrator as well as other advices here but still error message below pops up.

[IDE Fatal Errors]

```
C:\Users\hakmin\.AndroidStudio3.1\system\gradle\Projects\ff20177d\project.dat (access is denied)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\hakmin\.AndroidStudio3.1\system\gradle\Projects\ff20177d\project.dat (access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.data.ExternalProjectSerializer.save(ExternalProjectSerializer.java:234)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.data.ExternalProjectDataCache.saveExternalProject(ExternalProjectDataCache.java:85)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.data.ExternalProjectDataService.importData(ExternalProjectDataService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManagerImpl.doImportData(ProjectDataManagerImpl.java:271)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManagerImpl.importData(ProjectDataManagerImpl.java:145)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManagerImpl.importData(ProjectDataManagerImpl.java:221)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManagerImpl.importData(ProjectDataManagerImpl.java:228)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.doPopulateProject(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:117)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.populate(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:94)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.access$000(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:39)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask$1.run(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:84)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:713)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:543)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:488)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:165)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thank you.

Comment: probably the file is not present at that location or you don't have the permissions.

Comment: I'm afraid I found the file in the folder and added my user account and administrator for full access but it doesn't work.

Comment: I resolved this issue as I change the hidden folders making errors into visible ones.